# Erro org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException como resolver?

Tags: java, hibernate

Eu sei que esse erro é derivado de tentar buscar alguns dados a base de dados, quando não tenho nenhuma sessão aberta.

Mas o maior problema para mim é que esse erro está me a aparecer completamente aleatório, como estou a desenvolver um servidor que processa dados e depois envia para clientes, de 3 em 3 minutos o servidor repete as mesmas operações, mas o erro tanto aparece logo na execução do servidor como pode aparecer depois de 3 ou 4 horas de execução do servidor.

O erro aponta sempre para a classe `Produto` mais precisamente para o método `toString`, comentei o método e agora dá erro no `hashCode`.

*Estrutura na base de dados:*

|| Lote || ----Contem ---> || Produto || ----Contem ---> || qualityGates ||

Código -> Produto.java

```
public class Produto  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer idProduto;
     private Qualitygate qualitygateByIdQualityGate3;
     private Qualitygate qualitygateByIdQualityGate2;
     private Qualitygate qualitygateByIdQualityGate1;
     private Familiaproduto familiaproduto;
     private String noproduto;
     private Integer vt;
     private String tipo;
     private Set loteestados = new HashSet(0);

    public Produto() {
    }

//++ GET'S & SET'S

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 59 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.idProduto);
        hash = 59 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.qualitygateByIdQualityGate3); // <-----erro
        hash = 59 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.qualitygateByIdQualityGate2);
        hash = 59 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.qualitygateByIdQualityGate1);
        hash = 59 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.familiaproduto);
        hash = 59 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.noproduto);
        hash = 59 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.vt);
        hash = 59 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.tipo);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Produto other = (Produto) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.idProduto, other.idProduto)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.qualitygateByIdQualityGate3, other.qualitygateByIdQualityGate3)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.qualitygateByIdQualityGate2, other.qualitygateByIdQualityGate2)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.qualitygateByIdQualityGate1, other.qualitygateByIdQualityGate1)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.familiaproduto, other.familiaproduto)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.noproduto, other.noproduto)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.vt, other.vt)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.tipo, other.tipo)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return " noproduto=" + noproduto;
    }
//    @Override
//    public String toString() {
//        return "Produto{" + "idProduto=" + idProduto + ", qualitygateByIdQualityGate3=" + qualitygateByIdQualityGate3 + ", qualitygateByIdQualityGate2=" + qualitygateByIdQualityGate2 + ", qualitygateByIdQualityGate1=" + qualitygateByIdQualityGate1 + ", familiaproduto=" + familiaproduto + ", noproduto=" + noproduto + ", vt=" + vt + ", tipo=" + tipo + ", loteestados=" + loteestados + '}';
//    }

  }
```

Código -> Produto.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class catalog="mydb" name="Models.Produto" table="produto">
    <id name="idProduto" type="java.lang.Integer">
      <column name="idProduto"/>
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <many-to-one class="Models.Qualitygate" fetch="select" name="qualitygateByIdQualityGate3">
      <column name="idQualityGate3"/>
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one class="Models.Qualitygate" fetch="select" name="qualitygateByIdQualityGate2">
      <column name="idQualityGate2"/>
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one class="Models.Qualitygate" fetch="select" name="qualitygateByIdQualityGate1">
      <column name="idQualityGate1"/>
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one class="Models.Familiaproduto" fetch="select" name="familiaproduto">
      <column name="idNomeProduto"/>
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="noproduto" type="string">
      <column length="45" name="noproduto" not-null="true" unique="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="vt" type="java.lang.Integer">
      <column name="vt"/>
    </property>
    <property name="tipo" type="string">
      <column length="10" name="tipo"/>
    </property>
    <set fetch="select" inverse="true" lazy="true" name="loteestados" table="loteestado">
      <key>
        <column name="ProdutoidProduto" not-null="true"/>
      </key>
      <one-to-many class="Models.Loteestado"/>
    </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Código -> GenericoDao  Criação da sessão
*(No inicio tinha o `HibernateUtil` para me criar as sessões mas devido ao problema de criar muitas sessões e dar o erro de memoria cheia alterei para esta abordagem)*

```
public class GenericDao<T extends Serializable> {

    private static Session session;
    public Class<T> persistentClass;

    public GenericDao(){
        //this.session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) 
            getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    public Session createSession(){
            Configuration cfg= new Configuration().configure();
        SessionFactory sessionfactory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        session=sessionfactory.openSession();

        return this.session;
    }
    public Session getSession() {
        if(this.session == null || !this.session.isOpen()){  
           return createSession();
        } else return session;
    }

    protected void save(T entity) {

         try {

            Session session = getSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(entity);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();

        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

   }

// ----------------------- +outros métodos 

    public T findById(Integer id) {
        return (T) getSession().createCriteria(persistentClass)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("id", id)).uniqueResult();
    }


    private void close() {
        if (getSession() != null && getSession().isOpen()) {
            getSession().close();
        }
    }
}
```

Alguma solução para este problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, se você sempre usa acessa todos os atributos dos objetos, deveria usar o modo *eager* e não *lazy*.

Entretanto, o problema pode ter sua causa no fato de que, em determinadas circunstâncias, o Hibernate cria proxies nas entidades *lazy*, o que significa que ele não carrega os dados até interceptar uma chamada a um método *getter*.

Eu mesmo já tive problemas ao acessar atributos nesses tipos de objetos. Solução? Tente **chamar o método *getter*** ao invés de acessar os atributos diretamente.

Por exemplo, onde você faz isso:

```
hash = 59 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.idProduto);
```

Pode mudar para isso:

```
hash = 59 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.getIdProduto());
```

Comment: Podia postar uma linhas de código com os exemplos que deu? só para ver se percebi direito... por exemplo quando fala em chamar os métodos getter é isto: `this.objeto.getNome` em vez de `this.objeto` ? e já agora obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @jsantos1991 Atualizei a resposta

Comment: Obrigado pela edição, como o erro é aleatório deixa ver se resolve, se for o caso eu venho marcar como o certo.

Comment: voltou a dar o erro, depois de 4h a funcionar resolveu aparecer, não interrompeu o programa mas mesmo assim queria tentar resolver esse problema, sabes como posso mudar o meu mapeamento para `eager`? ou algum exemplo de uma boa implementação da sessão?

Comment: @jsantos1991 Sua Session deve estar sendo fechada em alguma situação. Como você gerencia as instâncias dos seus DAOs? Será que não é um problema de concorrência? Você guarda a session num atributo de classe, então se dois usuários acessarem o sistema ao mesmo tempo e compartilharem a mesma Session, um vai fechar a sessão do outro, entende? Acho que é melhor você definir uma [`SessionFactory`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html) global e recuperar uma nova Session local em cada método. Além disso, tente mudar `fetch="select"` para `fetch="join"`.

Comment: mais uma vez obrigado pela ajuda, eu já tive essa `sessionFactory` mas não consegui implementar la direito, o programa estourava(memoria cheia), vou fazer essas alterações, depois digo alguma coisa.

Comment: Ah quanto as estâncias, tenho no inicio do programa algo deste género `ProdutoDao prodDao=new ProdutoDAO();` e depois uso durante todo o programa quando necessito `prodDao.save(obejto)` é errado fazer assim?

Comment: é um sistema desktop, vou implementar esse `SessionFactory` a ver se consigo por isso a funcionar direito

Comment: @jsantos1991 O problema de usar a mesma session é relacionado à concorrência. Se houver mais de um processo rodando ao mesmo tempo eles usarão a mesma sessão e um poderá fechar a sessão do outro. Se o sistema não é web, mas local, então você poderia manter uma mesma session aberta o tempo todo. Só que se um processamento demorar mais que 3 minutos, então o próximo "encavalaria" e poderia dar problema. Tente remover o `session.close()` do método `save` e mudar para `fetch="join"` nos relacionamentos.

Comment: o `fetch ="join"` ja alterei, mas como o erro é aleatório não sei se consegui com isso resolver o problema, contudo e para finalizar este assunto, quando falas em remover `session.close()` referes te a todos os closes e assim trabalhar sempre com a mesma sessão certo?

Comment: @jsantos1991 Isso mesmo, a ideia seria trabalhar deixar a sessao aberta e trabalhar com a mesma. Se houver necessidade de abrir e fechar uma sessão, crie uma nova sessão em uma variável local do método, nunca numa variável compartilhada.

Comment: mais uma vez muito obrigado por toda a ajuda/explicação, vou marcar a resposta como certa visto que depois de conseguir implementar o problema deverá desaparecer...